# Templates, friend classes, and their constructors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'm awful at templates as it is. Not much instruction has ever been given to me. I'm having a lot of trouble getting my templated doubly linked list program for my data structures class to work. I finally got it to compile without error one time, but then it had a run-time fault (`what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid`) and crashed.

```
template<class T> class DoublyLinkedList; 
{...}
template<class T> class DListNode {
    ...
    friend class DoublyLinkedList<T>;
};
template<class T> class DoublyLinkedList {
    ...
    protected: DListNode<T> header, trailer;
    public:
        DoublyLinkedList<T>() : header(0), trailer(0) // constructor
        { header.next = &trailer; trailer.prev = &header; }
        DoublyLinkedList<T>(const DoublyLinkedList<T>& dll); // copy constructor
        ~DoublyLinkedList<T>(); // destructor
    ...
}
```

I'm supposed to declare the `DoublyLinkedList` class above `DListNode` because it is a friend right? The values of zero for `header` and `trailer` are zero because in the first part of the assignment where I had to create a non-template program just for lists of type `int`, and my professor just told us to copy and paste it into a new file and "transform" it to a templated version, so I know it probably shouldn't be zero.

The error I showed above happens right when the program reaches the first constructor in the main.cpp, `DoublyLinkedList<string>` dll; so I know it's the constructor that's causing that problem. Help please I'm very lost!

Comment: you're initializing a `std::string` (or possibly a `std::wstring`) with 0 as argument. that's invalid. it is however not shown in any of the code you're presenting here so far.

Comment: I realize that. But no matter what I put in as an argument for the constructor, it won't initialize for all types. So my problem is that I don't know how to make an "adaptive" constructor that initialize header and trailer to their owner's type's "null" value.

Comment: I guess I should have said that header and trailer are of type DListNode<T>. I'll add an edit.

Comment: @UnworthyToast: Use value-initialisation, `T()`, to zero-initialise primitive types and default-construct class types.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: as in `DoublyLinkedList<T>(): header(T()), trailer(T())`?

Comment: @UnworthyToast: Yes, assuming that the `DListNode` constructor uses its argument to initialise a `T` member. Alternatively, give `DListNode` a default constructor, and get that to value-initialise the member.

Comment: @UnworthyToast Slightly Related: If it helps at all (and likely it doesn't), I can't see any reason `DListNode` is a stand-alone template in the first place. It would at least seem to me `DoublyLinkedList ` should have a *nested* class, `Node`, that utilizes `T` from its surrounding `DoublyLinkedList` in the first place, and squelching all issues with friending in the process.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm supposed to declare the DoublyLinkedList class above DListNode
>   because it is a friend right?

Wrong. A friend declaration doubles as a forward declaration in the enclosing scope of the struct/class in which you place the friend declaration. So the following example forward declares class `ns::Bar`.

```
namespace ns {
class Foo
{
    friend class Bar;
};
} // namespace ns
```

> The values of zero for header and trailer are zero because in the
>   first part of the assignment where I had to create a non-template
>   program just for lists of type int, and my professor just told us to
>   copy and paste it into a new file and "transform" it to a templated
>   version, so I know it probably shouldn't be zero.

Sounds like a sensible approach, except that I suspect your non-template list class already has a problem. It should be possible to create an empty list, i.e. one that contains no nodes at all.

> The error I showed above happens right when the program reaches the
>   first constructor in the main.cpp, DoublyLinkedList dll;, so I
>   know it's the constructor that's causing that problem. Help please I'm
>   very lost!

You are likely calling the `std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*`. This constructor assumes the argument points to a valid null terminated character string.